# Ubuntu 10.10 root.disk copied to another computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my acer laptop [installed inside Windows] and it has all the graphics like Compiz and drivers installed in it. So what I did was installed the same version of Ubuntu 10.10 inside Windows to a Dell laptop with different hardware and then copied the root.disk file from Acer laptop to Dell laptop Ubuntu folder

Now it looks like the dell boots into Ubuntu but all the graphics have returned to stage one and the drivers are not installed.

Is there some command that I can type in terminal to get the Ubuntu system to re-initiate the drivers and compiz graphics?

Or can I type a command so that all drivers inside Ubuntu are re-scanned and re-installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying is not completely clear: what does it mean you are running Ubuntu 
*installed inside Window*? Are you running it as dual boot? From wubi? Inside a VirtualBox? The answer to this question may lead to different diagnostics.

Still, assuming that the problem is totally within Ubuntu, you may try these two commands:

```
sudo udevadm trigger
sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

The first one forces udev to make a re-appraisal of your hardware. It is most likely useless, but given the lack of info we might as well try, it surely won't hurt.

The second one tries to re-establish default configuration of the X server, forgetting the values it carried over from the previous installation on your Acer machine.

Comment: yes i am running ubuntu 10.10 as dual boot inside windows 7 on the old acer laptop [no vbox]...so i have done the same on the new dell laptop ubuntu 10.10 inside windows 7 using wubi and then copied the old acer ubuntu root.disk file to dell laptop....but now ubuntu on dell does not recognize the new hardware so i am not getting the same compiz graphics [ubuntu is working]...and also ubuntu 10.10 does not update cause its old.....so if there was a command for ubuntu to look inside its folders and organize the drivers by itself??

Comment: You should try the second command I gave you, dpkg-...

Comment: the second one worked.....my compiz settings are back...everything else seems to be working fine....im still checking....many thanks